# Word-embedding does not provide expected relations between words

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, word-embedding

I am trying to train a word embedding to a list of repeated sentences where only the subject changes. I expected that the generated vectors corresponding the subjects provide a strong correlation after training as it is expected from a word embedding. However, the angle between the vectors of subjects is not always larger than the angle between subjects and a random word.

```
Man   is going to write a very long novel that no one can read.
Woman is going to write a very long novel that no one can read.
Boy   is going to write a very long novel that no one can read.
```

The code is based on [pytorch tutorial](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/tutorials/master/beginner_source/nlp/word_embeddings_tutorial.py):

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

class EmbedTrainer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_vocab, d_embed, d_context):
        super(EmbedTrainer, self).__init__()
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(d_vocab, d_embed)
        self.fc_1 = nn.Linear(d_embed * d_context, 128)
        self.fc_2 = nn.Linear(128, d_vocab)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embed(x).view((1, -1)) # flatten after embedding
        x = self.fc_2(F.relu(self.fc_1(x)))
        x = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
        return x

text = " ".join(["{} is going to write a very long novel that no one can read.".format(x) for x in ["Man", "Woman", "Boy"]])
text_split = text.split()
trigrams = [([text_split[i], text_split[i+1]], text_split[i+2]) for i in range(len(text_split)-2)]
dic = list(set(text.split()))
tok_to_ids = {w:i for i, w in enumerate(dic)}
tokens_text = text.split(" ")
d_vocab, d_embed, d_context = len(dic), 10, 2

""" Train """
loss_func = nn.NLLLoss()
model = EmbedTrainer(d_vocab, d_embed, d_context)
print(model)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

losses = []
epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    for input, target in trigrams:
        tok_ids = torch.tensor([tok_to_ids[tok] for tok in input], dtype=torch.long)
        target_id = torch.tensor([tok_to_ids[target]], dtype=torch.long)
        model.zero_grad()
        log_prob = model(tok_ids)
        #if total_loss == 0: print("train ", log_prob, target_id)
        loss = loss_func(log_prob, target_id)
        total_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    print(total_loss)
    losses.append(total_loss)

embed_map = {}
for word in ["Man", "Woman", "Boy", "novel"]:
    embed_map[word] = model.embed.weight[tok_to_ids[word]]
    print(word, embed_map[word])

def angle(a, b):
    from numpy.linalg import norm
    a, b = a.detach().numpy(), b.detach().numpy()
    return np.dot(a, b) / norm(a) / norm(b)

print("man.woman", angle(embed_map["Man"], embed_map["Woman"]))
print("man.novel", angle(embed_map["Man"], embed_map["novel"]))
```

Comment: Probably not enough data. What is your training set size? If you train 128d embedding on 3 sentences that not unexpectable.

Answer (score 1):

> I expected that the generated vectors corresponding the subjects provide a strong correlation after training as it is expected from a word embedding

I don't really think you'll achieve that kind of result with only 3 sentences and like 40 iterations in 10 epochs (plus most of the data in your 40 iterations is repeated).

maybe try downloading a couple of free datasets out there, or try your own data with a proven model like a genism model.

I'll give you the code for training a gensim model, so you can test your dataset on another model and see if the problem comes from your data or from your model.
I've tested similar gensim models on datasets with millions of sentences and it worked like a charm, for smaller datasets you might want to change the parameters.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


corpus_path = 'eachLineASentence.txt'
vecSize = 300
winSize = 5
numWorkers = cpu_count()-1
epochs = 20
minCount = 5
skipGram = False
modelName = f'mymodel.model'

model = Word2Vec(corpus_file=corpus_path,
                size=vecSize,
                window=winSize,
                min_count=minCount,
                workers=numWorkers,
                iter=epochs,
                sg=skipGram)
model.save(modelName)
```

P.S. I don't think it's a good idea to use the keyword input as a variable in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably the training size. Training a 128d embedding is definitely overkill. Rule of thumb from the the [google developers blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-tensorflow-feature-columns.html):

> Why is the embedding vector size 3 in our example? Well, the following "formula" provides a general rule of thumb about the number of embedding dimensions: 
> `embedding_dimensions =  number_of_categories**0.25` 
> That is, the embedding vector dimension should be the 4th root of the number of categories. Since our vocabulary size in this example is 81, the recommended number of dimensions is 3: 
> `3 =  81**0.25`

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice equation. I remember trying with embed size of 3 too but didn't see much difference. The loss reduces and I expect to see some correlation, but nothing. Multiple runs, different results with no significant correlation.